# Understanding the implemention of sum function

Tags: haskell

I started to play a bit with Haskell and came across the following implementation of the `sum` function:

```
sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

And then there's an explanation that shows how the function would behave on a real example:

```
sum [1,2,3]

1 + (sum [2,3])
1 + (2 + sum [3])
1 + (2 + (3 + sum []))
1 + (2 + (3 + 0))
= 6
```

I don't understand, why every time `sum [x]` is called, the list gets smaller by 1 element?

My only assumption is that when the construction `(x:xs)` is executed, then the element `x` of the list, not only is retrieved, but also removed (similar to the stacks `pop()` method.), but I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the notation `x:xs`, x is the head of the list, which is 1 item, and xs is the tail of the list, which is a list of 0 or more items.

Since the recursive call is on xs, the problem size set gets reduced by 1 with each level of recursion.

Comment: This makes so much sense! My mistake was that I was trying to associate `(x:xs)`, with "for each element `x` in `xs` list"... similar to `foreach` in Java for example.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such a thing as "removing an element from a list". Lists are immutable, just like any other object. Now, with regards to the implementation, in:

```
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

you are pattern matching a list into it's head `x` and the rest of the list (without the head) `xs`. Specifically, in `sum [1, 2, 3]`, then you would get:

```
sum (1:[2, 3]) = 1 + sum [2, 3]
```

If you remember, `(:)` is used to append an element to a list. So: `1:[2, 3]` is actually `[1, 2, 3]` which can also be written as: `1:2:3:[]`.

The only thing that you should remember is that pattern matching on `(x:xs)`, means: put the head of a list in `x` and the rest of the list in `xs`.

Answer (score 2):

It's [recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion)

Basically, you're calling the function again with the rest of the list summed with the first element.